# Call a function in a function without returning any values

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-python-api

I'm new to programming, and I'm hoping for your help.
I need to make up a script where a function would be called in another function. At the same time, none of the functions should return anything, print() should be used to present the results.
I've come up with two simple functions:

```
def sum1(a,b,c):
    print (a+b+c)
```

and the other one that should count the arithmetic average of the a, b, and с from the 1st function. I've been trying to make the 2nd function call the 1st one and use the result to count the arithmetic average. I came up with sth like this but it won't work:

```
def ar():
    sum1()
    print (sum1/3)
```

Any ideas on how to make this whole thing work are greatly appreaciated!

Comment: "At the same time, none of the functions should return anything" seems like a totally ludicrous requirement. Just making sure, are you certain you've understood that correctly? Perhaps you've misinterpreted a requirement? Well, one thing you can do is to make the functions share-state, i.e. simply use global variables. This is a bad design approach, however. But it would solve this particular problem, albeit in a way that is not good.

Comment: As an aside, was taggin this with google-python-api a mistake?

Comment: The downvotes here are harsh. The OP has provided requirements, and has provided an attempt, which makes it pretty good as far as first-questions go.

Comment: So, here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/6ef776b0ad048c34457b6d8968e1816a) of what I mean, but again, you should really double-check if you've understood the requirements correctly.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're new to programming, and don't understand how functions are generally intended to be used. The proper way to design things is to have functions that perform computations and return results, and then other code that calls the functions and does something with the results, such as printing them.

Comment: You can do it using global variables, as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggests, but this is generally considered poor design, as he said. Since you're a beginner, this is the perfect time to learn good practices, not ask about nonsense like this.

Comment: @Barmar it sounds like a misunderstood assignment - or perhaps simply a poorly-designed assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Without returning anything from sum, there really isn't a way to do what you want unless you capture the sum from stdout. If the function doesn't return anything, then the second function won't be able to use it's results. You need to do.

```
def sum(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
def ar():
    print(sum(1, 2, 3)/3)
```

Comment: Say what you will about sharing state, relying on capturing standard out is probably even worse... Also, `sum_` in `sum` is *local*. So this will throw a `TypeError`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting capturing from stdout. I think that's a terrible idea. I was just saying what OP want's to do isn't really a reasonable solution. Yeah, definitely didn't even realize that about sum_. Very stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sure, yeah, didn't mean to imply that you were suggesting that, more of a general comment.